# Why does my C++ program crash on one machine and not on another?

Tags: c++

I have written a simple C++ program that I am compiling using g++ in command prompt and also running it through command prompt. The code of my program is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>

int main() 
{
    std::cout<<"Hello world"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code. I get a "hello_world.exe has stopped working" kind of error on my office machine. But when I run the same portion of code at home it works fine. Any idea why this is happening? Also, if I remove std::endl it works fine.

I am using Notepad++ to code.

UPDATE: I am not running the same binary on both machines. I compile on both the machines separately. I am using windows 7 32-bit at both the locations. I am using mingw. For compiling I type "g++ hello_world.cpp -o hello_world.exe". For running I typed "hello_world.exe". I downloaded mingw from the site mingw.org and used the "mingw-get-setup.exe" to install. And I installed g++ and gcc through the command prompt using the command "mingw-get install gcc g++".

Comment: Space radiation? Tectonic stress? Pentium FDIV bug?

Comment: What platforms (OS, and 64 vs 32 bit) are the machines

Comment: How do you compile this code? You don't try to run the same binary on both machines, do you?

Comment: I am not running the same binary on both machines. I compile on both the machines separately. I am using windows 7 32-bit at both the locations.

Comment: "Why does my C program crash" - and follows a C++ program. Now what?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I am not sure what your comment meant?

Comment: @Shaun: You did not provide enough details to answer the question.

Comment: @ Jesse Good: Can you tell me what other detail should I provide? I have a newbie I have no idea what else is important for answering this question.

Comment: @shaun: What toolchain are you using (mingw or cygwin downloaded from where) and what you typed at the command line.

Comment: I am using mingw. For compiling I typer "g++ hello_world.cpp -o hello_world.exe". For running I typed "hello_world.exe". I downloaded mingw from the site mingw.org and used the "mingw-get-setup.exe" to install. And I installed g++ and gcc through command prompt using the command "mingw-get install gcc g++".

Comment: Please remove my question from hold now. Or else let me know if there is any other info I need to provide.

Comment: @shaun: Everything sounds okay from the explanation. I can only guess that there is a conflict with a dll, or problem with the installation. Also, mingw.org is old and not updated frequently, I would recommend using [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: Is this related to my issue in any way?http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/1678/

Comment: It's the start of the zombie apocalypse.

Comment: Way to go before the zombie apocalypse begans because Jesse's suggestion worked and I think the bug is relevant because the version of gcc I use now is 4.6.2.......Thank you all for responding....Its a pain in the ass if something doesn't work and you can't figure out why...

Answer (score 1):

When you return from `main()`, your program stops working. In a gui-based environment, I wouldn't be surprised to see a pop-up message warning about a terminal-based application reaching completion where the user has to click "dismiss" before the terminal spawned to support the application is terminated as well. Windows 9x used to have such checkboxes in launcher preferences for MS-DOS programs.

Questions you should use to find out the issue are: 
  - Is it showing the same error message if you launch the shell yourself ?
  <s>- Do you use the very same binary on both machine, and if so, are your machines both capable of running it (e.g. not trying to launch a 64-bit binary on a 32-bit OS as one of the case)</s>

Comment: No thats not the case because I tried to run another program that crashed before it returned. Another program had a cin followed by a cout. Once I entered something for cin, pressed enter. it failed..

Comment: cin; cout; return 0; would let the program run until you entered something, then immediately produce output and terminate. You need some way to distinguish between "failed" and "terminated" here. On a shell you control, the return value should let you do the difference: if something makes it crash while invoking exit(0), you'll likely have a non-zero termination code for your process.

Comment: The "cout" in "cin;cout;return 0; doesn't happen. After "cin" i get "hello_world.exe has stopped working".

Answer (score 1):

It would help to see the exact text of the error message.

Your program depends on C and C++ runtime libraries.  I suspect you have the libraries installed on the machine where it works and don't where it doesn't, probably because you installed Visual Studio on the machine where you wrote the code but not on the machine where you're trying to run it.

You can install the runtime libraries on the second machine by search Microsoft Download for vcredist for the version of Visual Studio that you compiled the program with.

Comment: The text is basically all what I mentioned in the question.I tried running the code on both machines. And I compiled the code on both machines separately before I ran the code. I dint use visual studio for compiling. I used g++ from command prompt for compiling.

Comment: gcc likely also requires runtime libraries.  Try linking your program statically  to the runtime libraries.  That should make it portable.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me on Windows 7 32-bit using MinGW. I suspect that you've not installed all the  components you need to run the program. I would re-install MinGW and Msys and be sure you install all the necessary C and C++ components.

```
g++ --version
g++.exe (GCC) 4.6.2

a.exe
Hello World
```

I have used MinGW and Msys on Windows for many years (several different versions) and have never had issues compiling, linking or executing standard C and C++ programs.